# GetInfeasibleConstraints runtime error: Output must be of scalar type float

Tags: drake

I'm trying to debug my MP with the following

```
solver = IpoptSolver()
result = solver.Solve(prog)
result.GetInfeasibleConstraints(prog)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
PyFunctionConstraint: Output must be of scalar type float. Got AutoDiffXd instead.
```

I have autodiff constraints added similar to the way in the [compass gait example](https://colab.research.google.com/github/RussTedrake/underactuated/blob/master/exercises/simple_legs/compass_gait_limit_cycle/compass_gait_limit_cycle.ipynb#scrollTo=hADxwQQWe2wR).

e.g.

```
plant_autodiff = plant.ToAutoDiffXd()
def eq7h(q_v_r):
    q, v, r = np.split(q_v_r, [
        plant.num_positions(),
        plant.num_positions() + plant.num_velocities()])
    context = plant_autodiff.CreateDefaultContext()
    plant_autodiff.SetPositions(context, q)
    plant_autodiff.SetVelocities(context, v)
    return plant_autodiff.CalcCenterOfMassPosition(context) - r
prog.AddConstraint(eq7h, lb=[0]*3, ub=[0]*3, vars=np.concatenate([q[k], v[k], r[k]]))
```

How do I use `GetInfeasibleConstraints` correctly?

Comment: The constraint you added only support Eval with AutoDiffXd, not with float. Could you post the constraint function in your code?

Comment: Yes, my constraints are written for AutoDiff.  Is it necessary to write constraints to support both float and autodiff in order to use `GetInfeasibleConstraints`?  I suppose that means I need an `if` statement in the constraint that checks whether the input variables are autodiff or float and use the corresponding `plant`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetInfeasibleConstraints` requires the constraint to be evaluated with a vector of doubles. So I would re-write your constraint as

```
def eq7h(q_v_r):
    q, v, r = np.split(q_v_r, [
        plant.num_positions(),
        plant.num_positions() + plant.num_velocities()])
    # Select plant based on the data type of q_v_r. If the data type is autodiff (np.object in this case), then use plant_autodiff, otherwise use plant
    plant_eval = plant_autodiff if q_v_r.dtype == np.object else plant
    context = plant_eval.CreateDefaultContext()
    plant_eval.SetPositions(context, q)
    plant_eval.SetVelocities(context, v)
    return plant_eval.CalcCenterOfMassPosition(context) - r
```